# I have an "attribute" in a class. When I call it, it says it doesn't have that attribute

Tags: python, class, function, attributes

I have this code, what I'm trying to do is call the display function, but it gives me error. This is the code:

```
level = [0, 0, 0,
         0, 1, 0,
         0, 0, 0]

class player:
    def getPlayerLoc(self, level):
        for i in level:
            if level[level.index(i)] == 1:
                print level.index(i)

    def display(self, level, levelx, levely):
        for i in level:
            layer = ""
            for h in range(levely): 
                height = h+1
                if level.index(i) < levelx*height and level.index(i) >= levelx*h:
                    if level[level.index(i)] == 0:
                        layer = layer + " - "
                    elif level[level.index(i)] == 1:
                        layer = layer + " O "

                if height == levely:
                    print layer
                    layer = ""

p1 = player()
p1.getPlayerLoc(level)
p1.display(level, 3, 3)
```

And the output is:

```
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gamy.py", line 28, in <module>
    p1.display(level, 3, 3)
AttributeError: player instance has no attribute 'display'
```

This is quite strange, because it gets the attribute getPlayerLoc, but not display. Please help!

Comment: I wonder if your indentation is messed up.  The code works for me

Comment: it is working fine here, no errors.

Comment: @Plazmotech Binary see http://ideone.com/qTMwo

Comment: I'd advise initialising your class so it'll work in Python 3 as well, `class player(object):`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have some indention problems.
may enable the "show whitespace" feature in your ide.

try to move your display-method above getPlayerLoc.
if it getPlayerLoc fails, it will indicate a indention-error.